# How to modify the "Double Selected" code's background color in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

As following img, I double clicked "test1" in

```
var test1 = decimal.MaxValue;
```

The variable that is referenced elsewhere is shown in dark blue, I want to modify this blue color in Color Scheme?

[image]

Comment: I'm not using Rider (PhpStorm user).. but have a look at `General | Code | Identifier under caret` and perhaps `General | Search Results | Search result` as well. These 2 look like the most closes match for me right now. P.S. Actual names/path in Rider may differ a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I found it, it's here! Thanks @LazyOne, it's really helpful.

[image]